# Advanced Custom Fields Repeater inside product category (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently using ACF 5.  I have set up a repeater on the product categories.

I'm currently struggling with how to get it to output the information.  I am inside the acrhive-product loop and I am updating the following template that contains the content that gets outputting:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product_cat' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

In content-product_cat.php I have the following for each loop for the repeater.  All the basic information already shows, the title, the woocommerce category image etc.  Its the repeater I added to the categories themselves I can't get to show.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_field('attributes', 'product_cat_'.$term->term_id); 
    if($terms): ?>
        <ul>
    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
            <li>
             <?php the_sub_field('attribute'); ?>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled? You might want to. That might tell you, at least, if you have undefined objects/variables. How are you defining `$term->term_id`? I'd start there because without `term` you'll never even get into the `foreach()` loop. After that, I don't know enough about ACF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printed out the args first:

```
<?php print_r($category);?>
```

Then used its output to produce the following:

```
<?php 
        $cat_id = $category->term_id; //used below to get a the acf from the categories!
    ?>


<?php
        // $cat_id = $category->term_id;

        $terms_features = get_field('features', 'product_cat_'.$cat_id); 
        if($terms_features): 
            // print_r($terms_features); 
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $terms_features as $terms_feature ): 
        // print_r($term); 
        ?>
        <?php
          $image_icon = $terms_feature['icon'];
          $image_icon_show = $image_icon[sizes][large];
          // print_r($image_feature);
        ?>
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_icon_show;?>" />
                    <?php echo $terms_feature['description'];?>
                </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
```